# Pandas group by time with specified start time

Tags: python, pandas

-- Edit I noticed I had inputted times not as I intended. I converted the after 12pm times to the 24 hour clock convention. However, unutbu's answer should still be clear.

-- 2nd Edit. I changed the data to make a better example.

Below is a a time series indexed by date. I want to do an aggregation starting from a start_datetime and continuing its aggregation according to the timedelta below (9.5 hours = 34200 seconds).

```
def main():

    # start_datetime = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 8)
    # end_datetime = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 5, 30)
    s = pd.Series(
        np.arange(2, 10),
        pd.to_datetime([
            '20130101 7:34:04', '20130101 8:34:08', '20130101 10:34:08',
            '20130101 12:34:15', '20130101 13:34:28', '20130101 12:34:54',
            '20130101 14:34:55', '20130101 17:29:12']))

    print(s)
    bar_size = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60*60*9.5)
    time_group = pd.Grouper(
        freq=pd.Timedelta(bar_size), closed='left', label='right')
    foobar = s.groupby(time_group).agg(np.sum)
    print(foobar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running the above code will output the following:

```
2013-01-01 09:30:00     5
2013-01-01 19:00:00    39
Freq: 570T, dtype: int64
```

The pandas internals decides to starts grouping from midnight instead of 8:00 am. I cannot find a way to force the dataframe to begin grouping at 8:00 am. Does anyone have a solution using pandas functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `base=480` to shift the starting point by 480 minutes (8 hours). 
The units are in minutes because the Grouper frequency is `570T` (T, here, denotes minutes):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def main():

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 8)
    s = pd.Series(
        range(8),
        pd.to_datetime([
            '20130101 8:34:04', '20130101 10:34:08', '20130101 10:34:08',
            '20130101 12:34:15', '20130101 1:34:28', '20130101 3:34:54',
            '20130101 4:34:55', '20130101 5:29:12']))

    bar_size = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60*60*9.5)
    time_group = pd.Grouper(freq=bar_size, closed='left', label='right', 
                            base=480)
    foobar = s.groupby(time_group).agg(sum)
    print(foobar)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

yields

```
2013-01-01 08:00:00    22
2013-01-01 17:30:00     6
Freq: 570T, dtype: int64
```

---

Internally, when `pd.Grouper` is given a frequency, [a `TimeGrouper` is returned](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.20.3/pandas/core/groupby.py#L235):

```
In [81]: time_group
Out[81]: <pandas.core.resample.TimeGrouper at 0x7f1499a32198>
```

So the arguments passed to `pd.Grouper` are actually passed to `pd.TimeGrouper`.

```
In [82]: pd.TimeGrouper?
Init signature: pd.TimeGrouper(self, freq='Min', closed=None, label=None,
                               how='mean', nperiods=None, axis=0,
                               fill_method=None, limit=None, loffset=None,
                               kind=None, convention=None, base=0, **kwargs)
```

The `TimeGrouper` docs do not explain the `base` parameter, but it has the same meaning as in `df.resample`:

```
In [83]: df.resample?
Parameters
----------
base : int, default 0
    For frequencies that evenly subdivide 1 day, the "origin" of the
    aggregated intervals. For example, for '5min' frequency, base could
    range from 0 through 4. Defaults to 0
```

Comment: great answer!! Thank you!

Comment: This answer does not explain how would it work with a different start time than 8:00 am, especially a non-round timestamp, like 8:41:00.

Answer (score 1):

The following will allow you to slide the start to the dates forward eight hours:

```
(s.index + pd.Timedelta('9 hours 30 minutes')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
# array([u'2013-01-01', u'2013-01-01', u'2013-01-01', u'2013-01-01', 
# u'2013-01-01', u'2013-01-01', u'2013-01-01', u'2013-01-01'], 
# dtype='<U10')
```

You can then call:

```
s.groupby((s.index + pd.Timedelta('9 hours 30 minutes')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')).agg(sum)
# 2013-01-01    28
```

You can also rely solely on pandas datetime modules for your function, rather than separately importing `datetime`:

```
import pandas as pd


def main():

    start_datetime = pd.datetime(2013, 1, 1, 8)

    s = pd.Series(
        range(8),
        pd.to_datetime([
            '20130101 8:34:04', '20130101 10:34:08', '20130101 10:34:08',
            '20130101 12:34:15', '20130101 1:34:28', '20130101 3:34:54',
            '20130101 4:34:55', '20130101 5:29:12']))

    time_group = (s.index + pd.Timedelta('9 hours 30 minutes')).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    foobar = s.groupby(time_group).agg(sum)
    print(foobar)
```

Answer (score 0):

Very interestingly, the documentation for pandas.Grouper says:

> pandas.Grouper(key=None, level=None, freq=None, axis=0, sort=False)
>
> ...
>
> base : int, default 0
>
> ```
> Only when freq parameter is passed.
> ```

There is no explanation on the *base* parameter. And it is not even in the constructor argument list. It only says it takes int.
However, you can actually pass in float so that it can shift grouping interval by a fraction of period. For example, if your freq='1D' and you put base=0.5, the group boundary will be 12pm everyday, rather than 0am.

Answer (score 0):

**pandas 1.1.0** introduced the `origin` parameter with a straight forward way of achieving this (also note the `9h30min` notation for `freq`, more notations [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#offset-aliases)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.to_datetime([
            '2013-01-01 8:34:04', '2013-01-01 10:34:08', '2013-01-01 10:34:08',
            '2013-01-01 12:34:15', '2013-01-01 1:34:28', '2013-01-01 3:34:54',
            '2013-01-01 4:34:55', '2013-01-01 5:29:12']), columns =['the_date'])
# dummy column with ones
df['other'] = 1

# sum the other column aggregated by the date
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='the_date',freq='9h30min', origin='start'))['other'].sum()
```

---

For **pandas < 1.1.0** you can do this for a more generic solution:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='the_date',freq='9h30min', 
                     base=df.the_date.min().hour * 60 + df.the_date.min().minute))['other'].sum()
```

Basically, you can use the min date to calculate the base (`df.the_date.min().hour * 60 + df.the_date.min().minute`).

[Link to documenation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

(`base` was also deprecated in this version)