# pandas resample timed events in DataFrame to precise time-bins

Tags: python, pandas, resampling

maybe I could not find it... anyhow, with pandas '0.19.2' there is the following

### problem:

I have some timed events of associated groups which can be generated by:

```
from numpy.random import randint, seed
import pandas as pd

seed(42)    # reproducibility

samp_N = 1000
# create times within 3 hours, and 15 random groups
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': randint(0,3*60*60, samp_N), 
                   'group': randint(0, 15, samp_N)})
# make a resample-able index from the seconds time values
df.set_index(pd.TimedeltaIndex(df.time, 's'), inplace=True)
```

which looks like:

```
          group   time
02:01:10     10   7270
00:14:20     13    860
01:29:50      9   5390
01:26:31     13   5191
...
```

When I try to resample the events, I get something undesirable

```
df.resample('5T').count()

          group  time
00:00:04     28    28
00:05:04     18    18
00:10:04     32    32
...
```

Unfortunately the resampling periods start at arbitrary (first in data) offset values.
It is even more annoying if I group this (as ultimately required)

```
df.groupby('group').resample('5T').count()
```

then I get a new offset for each group
what I want is the precise start of sampling windows:

```
00:00:00   5 ...
00:05:00  17 ...
00:10:00  11 ...
...
```

there was a suggestion in: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23966229

```
df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('5Min')).count()
```

but it does not work either, as it also ruins the grouping required above.

thanks for hints!

Comment: What do you mean by "but it does not work either, as it also ruins the grouping required above"? Your last trial seems to give good to me. Although you may write it as `df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')).count()` as there is a deprecation warning on `TimeGrouper`

Comment: What about `df.groupby(['group', pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')]).count()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i didn't come up with a nice solution but rather a work around. I added a dummy row with time value zero and then grouped by time and group:

```
df = pd.Series({'time':0,'group':-1}).to_frame().T.set_index(pd.TimedeltaIndex([0], 's')).append(df)
df = df.groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='5Min'), 'group']).count().reset_index('group')
df = df.loc[df['group']!=-1]
df.head()
        group  time
0 days      0     2
0 days      1     4
0 days      2     3
0 days      3     1
0 days      4     2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the result you want:

```
result = df.groupby(['group', pd.Grouper(freq='5Min')]).count().reset_index(level=0)
result.head()
>>>        group  time
00:05:00      0     2
00:10:00      0     1
00:15:00      0     3
00:20:00      0     2
00:30:00      0     1
result.sort_index().head()
>>>       group  time
0 days     10     1
0 days     14     3
0 days      2     1
0 days     13     1
0 days      4     3
```

Comment: you must have hit the :00 seconds for group 0.
otherwise I don't see how this could work.
It does not for me at least.
getting:

              group  time
    00:00:23      0     1
    00:10:23      0     3
    00:15:23      0     4
    ...

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Could you add a `random_seed` to your `randint` calls so that I can work with the exact same dataframe as you do? Also I tested with pandas 0.22. Is using pandas 0.19 a requirement for you?

Comment: 0.19 is not a requirement, just my default ubuntu version
and maybe that is the problem, which got changed in a later pandas version...

with inserted seed and @Prikers code I get:
`
           group  time
00:00:04     28    28
00:05:04     18    18
00:10:04     32    32
`

Comment: would you mind checking with the seed @Prikers ?
- thanks!

Comment: Hum, you are right, I get the same result using this seed: there are 4 seconds in all groups... I tried playing with the `base` (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45886936/pandas-group-by-time-with-specified-start-time) parameter but did not manage to obtain the correct result

Comment: yeah, tried base too.
and loffset.
but nothing works like desired.
the documentation is quite poor too (no good examples)
thanks anyways!