# How to group daily data weekly starting from date of first row then group data counts as columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, count, grouping

I have several rows of daily data per day like this:

```
Date       | Operation  | Condition | Type      |Location
2019/01/01 | Sale       | Used      |Commercial |32
2019/01/01 | Rent       | Used      |Housing    |2
2019/01/01 | Sale       | New       |Housing    |20
2019/01/01 | Sale       | New       |Housing    |15
2019/01/01 | Rent       | New       |Commercial |1
```

that I need to convert to weekly getting the counts from 3 columns, each column has only 2 possible values so I'd like to have 8 columns representing all possible 8 combinations of values for each and all of the different locations for each location:

```
Week                  |Commercial-Rent-New|Comercial-Sale-New|Comercial-Rent-Used|Commercial-Sale-Used...+ 4 Housing cols
2019/06/01-2019/06/07 |328                |1284              |2003               |4916 
2019/06/08-2019/06/15 |214                |2015              |2551               |5025 
2019/06/16-2019/06/23 |400                |1379              |1795               |3580 
...
2022/01/01-2019/01/07 |288                |1977              |1643               |5211
```

So far reading from articles and other posts from this site, I have grouped my DataFrame using this answer from a [post][1]

```
#convert date column to datetimes
 df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

 df1 = df.resample('W', on='date')['count1','count2'].sum()
```

I don't know it this approach is what I need because it's only outputing the start of the week and I can't figure how to count the rows for each combination of values into the 8 columns I mentioned earlier. I read that I could also use groupby function but as I am still very new to Python I'm kinda lost. I'd appreciate any help! Thanks in advance.
[1]: [Pandas Group by date weekly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59246839/pandas-group-by-date-weekly)

Comment: What you can try is to use Time Grouper `pd.TimeGrouper`

Comment: An [answer to a similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45887112/10394971)

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to format the "Week" Column of your DataFrame first. Then calculate the sum of the Locations.

Also it looks like you ultimately want to pivot the data so the Categories are set as Column Headers rather than row values.

Here is a solution option for your problem statement:

---

The following solution uses the datetime.timedelta function. You will need to import it,

```
from datetime import timedelta
```

To begin with the example in the problem statement - the DataFrame looks like this,

```
     Date Operation Condition        Type  Location
0  1/1/19      Sale      Used  Commercial        32
1  1/1/19      Rent      Used     Housing         2
2  1/1/19      Sale       New     Housing        20
3  1/1/19      Sale       New     Housing        15
4  1/1/19      Rent       New  Commercial         1
```

Picking up from your code, we start with formatting the Date column as a datetime object

```
# Format Date column as a datetime object
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

From here, create the Week column with the format you prefer. (There are different options for how to do this, the way I have shared here is very explicit)

```
# Make a column for the date of the start of the week
df['Week_Start'] = df['Date'].dt.to_period('W').apply(lambda x: x.start_time)

# Make a column with the date for the Week End
df['Week_End'] = df['Week_Start'] + timedelta(days=6)

# Convert the Week_Start and Week_End columns to String format
df['Week_Start'] = df['Week_Start'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))
df['Week_End'] = df['Week_End'].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y/%m/%d'))

# Create a Week column that concatenates the Week_Start and Week_End strings
df['Week'] = df['Week_Start'] + "-" + df['Week_End']
```

You will also need to format the Category names to the format you prefer

```
# Make a column with the categories 
df['Category_Name'] = df[['Type', 'Operation', 'Condition']].agg('-'.join, axis=1)
```

Now the DataFrame looks like this,

```
        Date Operation Condition        Type  Location  Week_Start         Category_Name    Week_End                   Week
0 2019-01-01      Sale      Used  Commercial        32  2018/12/31  Commercial-Sale-Used  2019/01/06  2018/12/31-2019/01/06
1 2019-01-01      Rent      Used     Housing         2  2018/12/31     Housing-Rent-Used  2019/01/06  2018/12/31-2019/01/06
2 2019-01-01      Sale       New     Housing        20  2018/12/31      Housing-Sale-New  2019/01/06  2018/12/31-2019/01/06
3 2019-01-01      Sale       New     Housing        15  2018/12/31      Housing-Sale-New  2019/01/06  2018/12/31-2019/01/06
4 2019-01-01      Rent       New  Commercial         1  2018/12/31   Commercial-Rent-New  2019/01/06  2018/12/31-2019/01/06
```

From here you can sum the Locations using group by and sum functions. You will want to reset the index as well so we can continue to call the columns by their names

```
# Sum the locations, grouped by the Week and the Category Name 
sum_df = df.groupby(['Category_Name','Week'])['Location'].sum().reset_index()
```

The summed DataFrame looks like this,

```
          Category_Name                   Week  Location
0   Commercial-Rent-New  2018/12/31-2019/01/06         1
1  Commercial-Sale-Used  2018/12/31-2019/01/06        32
2     Housing-Rent-Used  2018/12/31-2019/01/06         2
3      Housing-Sale-New  2018/12/31-2019/01/06        35
```

The final step in this solution is to Pivot the DataFrame so you have the Category Names as Column Headers, while still keeping the Week Column

```
# Pivot the data to make the Category Names into Columns Headers
formatted_df = sum_df.pivot(index='Week', columns='Category_Name', values='Location').fillna(0).reset_index()
```

The final DataFrame looks like this,

```
Category_Name                   Week  Commercial-Rent-New  Commercial-Sale-Used  Housing-Rent-Used  Housing-Sale-New
0              2018/12/31-2019/01/06                    1                    32                  2                35
```

Comment: Hi! Impressive and in-depht answer! I truly appreciate your help! I'm still watching some pandas tutorials to better grasp its possibilities. I'll implement your solution and report back to you. Thanks again!!!